# R pipe operator for indexing

Tags: r, function, indexing, pipeline

I want to have the same kind of pipe operator as dplyr's `%>%`, but for indexing instead of passing functions. For example I want to define function `%l%` such that for at least vectors and matrices:

`1 %l% df` would be equivalent to `df[1]` (vector) or `df[1,]` (matrices).

```
abc <- c("a","b", "c")
def <- c("d","e", "f")
df <- data.frame(abc, def, stringsAsFactors = F) 
df %l% 1
```

Comment: `df %l% 1` in your example is `df %>% slice(1)`, and `1 %>% slice(.data = df)` for the opposite order.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this, for example. Subsetting rows and columns for both vectors and matrices / data.frames.

```
`%l%` <- lineindex <- function(x, y) {
  result <- NA
  if(is.null(dim(y))|(!is.null(dim(y))&ncol(y)==1)) {
    result <- y[x]
  } else if(length(dim(y))==2) {
    result <- y[x,]
  } 
  return(result)
}
   `%c%` <- colindex <- function(x, y) {
  result <- NA
  if(is.null(dim(y))|(!is.null(dim(y))&ncol(y)==1)) {
    result <- y[x]
  } else if(length(dim(y))==2) {
    result <- y[,x]
  }
  return(result)
}

c(1,NA,2) %>% is.na() %>% which() %l% df 
  abc def
2   b   e
c(1,NA,2) %>% is.na() %>% which() %c% df 
[1] "d" "e" "f"
```